# Custom Pipeline Step never called

Tags: data-exchange-framework

Using DEF 2.0.1 and Sitecore 9.0.1, I have a custom pipeline step to publish items that have been updated

```
[RequiredPipelineStepPlugins(new Type[] { typeof(EndpointSettings) })]
class PublishSitecoreItemStepProcessor : BasePipelineStepProcessor
{
    protected override void ProcessPipelineStep(PipelineStep pipelineStep, PipelineContext pipelineContext, ILogger logger)
    {
```

I can add a break point to the ProcessPipelineStep and it's never hit. The processor step us using my own template which inherits from Base Pipeline Step. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which Template do you use for this pipeline step? Can you add here also screenshots of DEF related sections of item like Administration, Endpoints, ...

Comment: Under "Administration" section, is this pipeline step Enabled? Just to be sure :)

Comment: This is similar to the issue I am having. I have been working with Sitecore support on resolving it. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11396/data-exchange-framework-2-0-1-not-calling-readresult

Comment: Hi @PeterProchazka. Yes, the pipeline step is enabled. I've edited my question to include the processor type template (Base Pipeline Step). Endpoint is a standard Sitecore Item Model Repository Endpoint

Comment: Did you specify supported template id for the converter?

Comment: Vlad - you were spot on. I added to the template as a supported ID to the converter and that fixed that issue. If you put it is an answer, I can accept it ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Us we figured out from comments the problem was in the converter for created custom pipeline step.

The fix is to specify supported template id for the converter.

```
[SupportedIds("[TEMPLATE ID]")]
```